# Como alinhar um texto no meio da altura de uma imagem?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tentei várias formas e ainda não consegui, sou meio novo com CSS, queria que esse "Nome" ficasse na altura que bate com o meio da imagem ao lado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia postar algum exemplo de código? A forma mais adequada de resolver o seu problema pode depender de como seu HTML e CSS estão agora.

Comment: Um line-height pode te ajudar.

Comment: publique o código que você esta usando por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou deixar um código que você vai posicionar seu texto onde desejar, alterando os valores de

`top: 20px; left: 120px;` no css

```css
.image { 

   position: relative; 

   width: 100%; /* para IE 6 */
}
.h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 20px; 
   left: 120px; 
   width: 100%; 
}

.h2 span { 
   color: blue; 
   font: bold 14px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
}
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNpu1.png" alt="" />
  
 <h2  class="h2"><span>La Treta<span class='spacer'></span></h2>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente você vai usar o `display: table-cell` na caixa em que você quer estilizar a posição vertical do texto e depois usar o `vertical-align: middle`, mas aí você precisa definir uma altura pra essa caixa também.

No entanto, talvez com `display: flex` seja muito mais simples e menos feioso. Eu, se fosse você, ia estudar como ele se comporta. Hoje tô velho demais pra aprender essa vompra... =P

Answer (score 0):

Basta aplicar na imagem vertical-align: middle.

Por padrão, as imagens se posicionam ao rodapé da linha. Veja este exemplo como é simples:

Html:

```
<div>
  <img class="middle" src="http://placehold.it/100x50" alt=""> Teste
</div>
```

Css:

```
.middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Link do exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/rq3jresz/

Um outro link muito útil e este site que você responde as perguntas e ele te da o código final de como centralizar o conteúdo. http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score -3):

Normalmente você vai usar o `display: table-cell` na div em que você quer mudar a posição vertical do texto e depois usar o `vertical-align: middle` na própria div, mas aí você precisa definir uma altura para essa div também.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).